# Model Averaging: Standard Error vs Adjusted Standard Error

Tags: r, aic, model-averaging

I'm having trouble understanding when to use Std. Error or Adjusted SE in model averaging (model.avg). What/Why/When to use Adjusted SE? This is my code:

```
> summary(mdavg)
Component model call: 
lm(formula = <7 unique values>, data = MA_data)
Component models: 
       df  logLik   AICc delta weight
23      4  -96.07 200.68  0.00   0.25
13      6  -93.93 201.02  0.34   0.21
3       3  -97.41 201.14  0.46   0.20
123     7  -92.83 201.22  0.54   0.19
2       3  -98.64 203.60  2.92   0.06
12      6  -95.60 204.35  3.67   0.04
(Null)  2 -100.23 204.61  3.93   0.04
Term codes: 
yr.code     age      BW 
      1       2       3 
Model-averaged coefficients:  
(conditional average) 
             Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   1.03200    1.22743     1.23930   0.833   0.4050  
age           0.08546    0.05461     0.05548   1.540   0.1235  
BW            0.08255    0.03523     0.03579   2.306   0.0211 *
yr.codeone   -0.16072    0.26381     0.26794   0.600   0.5486  
yr.codethree  0.19479    0.25988     0.26415   0.737   0.4609  
yr.codetwo   -0.45875    0.23784     0.24174   1.898   0.0577 .
```

In Burnham & Anderson 2002 they talk about Adjusted Standard Errors but it is going over my head:

> We will hazard a suggestion here; it has not been evaluated in this context, but a similar procedure worked in a different context. If for each fitted model we have degrees of freedom $df_i$ for the estimator ${\rm Var}(\hat θ_i|g_i)$, then for generally small degrees of freedom one might try using the interval $\hat θ_i ± z_{1−α/2} {\rm ase}(\hat θ_i)$, where the adjusted standard error estimator is
>
> [image]